# Shutting down machine without having to press the physical button

Tags: shutdown, windows-server-2003

On a Windows Server 2003, whenever we want to shut it down, after Windows completed its stops, we have a display saying that we can now properly shut down the machine.

"It is now safe to shut down your computer"

It forces us to physically press the button to terminate the shutdown process.

Is there a way to disable that behavior and simply shut down the machine as soon as windows is shut down ?

This is the screen I mean

[image]

Comment: How are you instigating the shut down?

Comment: Manually, on Windows, by simply pressing "Start -> Shut Down computer".

Comment: What happens if you do 'shutdown.exe /s' from the command-line?

Comment: Same behavior... I suspect it is something related to ACPI. I've found something here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810903.

Comment: is this windows 98?

Comment: Does this help, try the setting at -1 or 0 ... [this](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1963-it-is-now-safe-to-turn-off-your-computer) or [this](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-98-2000-me-xp-2003-vista/423715-stupid-xp-shutdown-showing-now-safe-turn-off-your-computer.html) - I had actually forgotten about that dreadful screen!

Comment: Hehe, it's not Windows 98, It's actually Windows 2003 Server. I was surprised, just as you, that I would get (again) this black screen :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force “it's now safe to turn off your computer” screen in Windows XP when shutting down?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20352941/995714). This screen can appear on any modern Windows version if you want